# jsp response.redirect causes problems with jquery.mobile

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

My application is build with jsp pages and jquery.mobile. I use a Java function to check login status and do a redirect when that's not OK from within a Bean like this:

```
public String getMenu(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response, MenuType menuType, CurrentPage currentPage)
{
    if (session.getAttribute("state") == LoginChecked.UNDEFINED))
    {
        response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp");

        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
```

The problem is that the redirect to index.jsp is handled by jquery.mobile as an ajax reload of the content of the page, and not a complete redirect.

How can I force a complete reload of the browser of the index.jsp page?

-- ADDED --

Within html this would be solved with the "rel" attribute like this, so I would need some kind of method to use this rel from within my Java sendRedirect:

```
<a href='../index.jsp' data-role='button' data-icon='plus' rel='external'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at solving a similar problem myself recently (actually redirecting when an AJAX request is redirected), and found a very good answer on here that I apparently didn't bookmark. However, having successfully implemented it for myself, I'll share the approach I took based on that answer.

The first stage was to identify AJAX requests so they can be handled differently to standard requests. This can be done by checking the value of the `X-Requested-With` request header; a value of `XMLHttpRequest` indicates an AJAX request. In the case of a standard request, we proceed with the redirect as normal. In the case of handling an AJAX request, rather than proceeding with the redirect, what I did is set a response header to signify that a redirect *would* have occurred, and set its value to the URL that I want to redirect to.

Then, I used the following jQuery code to check all completed AJAX requests, and redirect when appropriate:

```
$(document).bind('ajaxComplete', function(event, xhr, options) {
    var redirectHeader = xhr.getResponseHeader('YourHeader');
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && redirectHeader != null) {
        window.location.href = redirectHeader;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

within **ajax** you will have to do like this :

```
success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
}
```

this will redirect you to **webpage** specified within `data` by the **server**

Comment: That's fine if the page you're being redirected to returns JSON data, which likely isn't going to be the case for a login page.

Comment: point is to have some var, flag for the server to tell the ajax parsing code to redirect. Could be a special header, could be a unique string in the respone like "NO_RESOPONSE_REDREICT_TO:http...url..." parse that and go to the url

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Ajax calls don't support redirect (call always ends at caller end). You may need to identify the response code on client side and do client side redirect like window.location(href)

Answer (score -1):

I have such a problem too, and I have found a effective solution, hope it can help you:

This has something to do with AJAX, and my solution is :
add `data-ajax="false"` as an attribute of your `<form>`. Just like I did:

```html
<form id="reg-input" action="/Myservlet" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <!-- .. -->
</form>
```

this will cause your ajax unavailable, take care.

Comment: This seems totally unrelated to the actual question. I'm also pretty sure just randomly adding `data-ajax="false"` to your `<form>` tag isn't going to do anything at all.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist , actually it does do something, but it's not something needed for the question.