# Response sendRedirect not working with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, extjs, extjs3

I have a web application with java and EXT JS(3.4).
For all servlets, this is what I have in my doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.sendRedirect("ErrorPage.jsp");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        //do some logging
    }
}
```

I simulate a GET request, with EXT JS using:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'web'//web is the servlet name
});
```

The page does not redirect. This is the output from tamperData plugin of firefox:

[image: Tamper Data Output]

If you are unable to see image, it says that the AJAX Get request responded with status 302:meaning redirect, and there was a request for ErrorPage.jsp which returned a status code of 200:meaning that the request completed successfully.
If i alert the response in the callback of the ajax request, it alerts the contents of the ErrorPage.jsp. I have a large number of such AJAX requests. Is there any reason why the redirect is not working.

I added the following code as well. But i always get status as 200. When though i can see in firebug that for a get request first request gave status 302 and the second one for Error  Page gave 200.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function(conn, response, options) {
                alert('successful'+response.status)
            });
            Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(conn, response, options) {
                alert('failed'+response.status)
            });
```

Details:

OS : Windows 7
Server : Apache Tomcat 7.0.42
Servlet Api: Using servlet-api-3.0.jar

Comment: It looks like Ext.js treats a 302 response status as an error, so you'll need to handle it in your code. See http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?30278-Following-HTTP-Redirects-(302)

Comment: That's kind of just how AJAX requests work, in my experience. I've posted an answer on one way to resolve that before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11722563/552438) (uses jQuery), you should be able to adapt that to fit your needs. From Frank's link it looks like there may be other ways of solving it in Ext JS.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist looks promising, will try this and post a solution if it works

Comment: Do you really need to redirect? Can't you embed "ErrorPage.jsp" in a Panel? I think there are some IFrame UX for Ext.

Comment: @code4jhon Nope..If u see the posted code, i am trying to forbid GET requests throughout the application. Implementing IFrame everywhere would be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @AnthonyGrist's post, this is the solution i came up with for EXT JS.
 In the controller I changed doGet to :

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
       response.setStatus(403);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

A status code of 403 is recognised in EXT JS as a failure.So in the jsp page :

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(conn, response, options) {
           if(response.status=403){
                window.location.assign("ErrorPage.jsp");
 }
});
```